# Display different view in popup or html div based on clicking url action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**How can I display a view in popup or in different div location in the original view based on the call to different action in the controller**.

I tried to use ajax call but it didn't work. I don't know why. I used a jquery model dialog but it redirect the user to another empty background page and display the popup.

**It's important that not to change the original page.**

I appreciate any help.

```
function ButtonClick(x) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "Tasks/AddWorkersToTask",
        data: { id: x },
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Content").html(data);
              alert('success');
        }
    });
    return false;
}


<a class="Tab" href="#" onclick="ButtonClick('@Model.PK_TaskID');"> AJAX Call </a>

<div id="Content">  </div>
```

**Edit**
The error in the console is : Empty string passed to getElementById().

This function works well. i tried to test it in case action Link and it successfully add the data.

```
    public ActionResult AddWorkersToTask(int id=0)
    {
        TempData["TaskID"] = id;
        return PartialView();

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddWorkersToTask(FormCollection form, string textbox1,string TaskID)
    {
```

Comment: Post your `AddWorkersToTask()` method. What errors do you have in the console? (and it probably should be `url: "/Tasks/AddWorkersToTask",`)

Comment: It should be GET not POST. Is your controller method being hit?

Comment: No it is not. I think the problem is with js function.

Comment: Again. Is your controller method method being hit? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: no it is not being hit. and The error in the console is : Empty string passed to getElementById().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61186/discussion-between-hanouf-d-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at your signatures in your controller. The AJAX request needs to match this.

```
type: "POST",
data: { id: x }

public ActionResult AddWorkersToTask(int id=0)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddWorkersToTask(FormCollection form, string textbox1,string TaskID)
```

If you are targeting the `HttpPost` you have the wrong signature. Or it needs to be a `GET` request. Your AJAX should have thrown you an error which you would need to capture with the `.error()` callback.

Comment: I changed the type. but sill no data is being displayed.